# Converting rows/strings into a single column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

If I have the following object

```
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

How do I convert it to this so that I can put it in one column and it aligns with my other columns in my data frame:

```
0
1
0
0
0
0
0
```

I thought `list` might work...but which function should this work on

So sorry for asking a suppose to be basic question...

Comment: I guess that you're looking for `cbind`, but I can't be more specific without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5964905) of what objects you have.

Comment: I think that might be a vector, not a string.  I would suggest going through one of the many online tutorials or pick up a book.

Comment: Blue Magister and Nathan are right. If you only want to transpose vectors you can use the `t` function

Comment: Just use `dataframe$newcolumnname <- string `. Your *string* actually looks a lot like a numeric vector which is entirely different.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `data.frame` say, "DF", like this:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=1:9, y=letters[1:9])
```

And you've a `vector` z:

```
z <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

**Note** that the number of rows in your `data.frame` and the length of the `vector` has to be the same if you want to add the `vector` to a `data.frame` as a new column.

```
dim(DF) # dimensions of data.frame
# [1] 9 2

length(z) # length of vector
# [1] 9
```

Now, you can use `cbind` to get the new column as follows:

```
cbind(DF, z)
#   x y z
# 1 1 a 0
# 2 2 b 1
# 3 3 c 0
# 4 4 d 0
# 5 5 e 0
# 6 6 f 0
# 7 7 g 0
# 8 8 h 0
# 9 9 i 0
```

---

If you have a `vector` whose length is not equal to that of the `data.frame` rows, then,

```
z <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) # length is 7

cbind(DF, z)
# Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
#   arguments imply differing number of rows: 9, 7
```

`cbind`'ing results in error due to unequal lengths. In this case, I could think of a couple ways to store this as a `list`.

First, you can keep your `data.frame` DF as such and create a `list` with its first element as the `data.frame` and the second as a `vector` as follows:

```
my_l <- list(d1 = DF, d2 = z)

# $d1
#   x y
# 1 1 a
# 2 2 b
# 3 3 c
# 4 4 d
# 5 5 e
# 6 6 f
# 7 7 g
# 8 8 h
# 9 9 i
# 
# $d2
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Alternatively, you can convert your `data.frame` to a `list` (a `data.frame` is internally a `list`) and create a `list` whose elements are all `vectors` as follows:

```
my_l <- c(as.list(DF), list(z=z))

# $x
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
# 
# $y
# [1] a b c d e f g h i
# Levels: a b c d e f g h i
# 
# $z
# [1] 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
```

Note that `as.list` coerces a `data.frame` columns to a `list` with it's names the column names of the `data.frame`. We then create a new `list` z and then `concatenate` using the `c` operator.

Hope this betters your understanding a bit.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Aruns great and detailed answer, there are two things worth noting:

First, `R` recycles shorter items to match the length of the longer items.  In the case of adding a vector to a data.frame, this will only occur if the number of rows of the data.frame is an exact multiple of the length of the vector.

```
 zshort <- c(1, 2, 3)

# will be `0` if exact multiple:
length(zshort)  %/% nrow(DF)
# [1] 0

cbind(DF, zshort)
#  cbind(DF, zshort)
#  x y zshort
#  1 a      1
#  2 b      2
#  3 c      3
#  4 d      1   <~~ Recycling
#  5 e      2
#  6 f      3
#  7 g      1   <~~ Recycling
#  8 h      2
#  9 i      3
```

(2) You can also add a new column to a data.frame using "[" as follows:

```
# name of the column does NOT have to be
#  the same as the name of the vector
DF[, "newName"] <- z

DF[, "shortz"]  <- zshort

# You can also delete existing columns
DF[, "y"]  <- NULL

DF
#   x newName shortz
#   1       1      1
#   2       2      2
#   3       3      3
#   4       1      1
#   5       2      2
#   6       3      3
#   7       1      1
#   8       2      2
#   9       3      3
```

Comment: (+1) for the first part about recycling. It's important and I seem to have missed it.